# Where did the ability "Paper cut" come from?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, pcgen

One of the players in my group uses PCGen to make her sheets, and she seems to have accidentally added a weird property to her bow for free. It claims to be from the Bestiary 3 and be called "Paper Cut", but there's no cost associated with it. It seems like it deals bleed damage on hit. What is this meant to be, some kind of monster ability? Is this a weird PC Gen only thing? Or a transcription error?

Here's the weapon in question:

[image]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I've looked at the PCGen data files, and it would appear that the Paper Cut ability is purely an artifact of PCGen.

The Paper Cut modifier appears to be part of the implementation of the [Contract Devil](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/devil/devil-contract/) creature, which originates from Bestiary 3, on p76 (also listed as the the reference page for the Paper Cut ability in PCGen). It should not be available or usable by player characters, only for those specific creatures. Your player has found and made use of a bug.